# Simpler processing of shell script options

Tags: bash, command-line, options, getopts

I'm looking for way to process shell script arguments that is cleaner and more "self documenting" than getopt/getopts.

It would need to provide...

- Full support of long options with or without a value after '=' or ' '(space).
- Proper handling of hyphenated option names (i.e. --ignore-case)
- Proper handling of quoted option values (i.e. --text "A text string")

I would like to eliminate the overhead of the big loop with embedded case statement that getopt/getopts requires and reduce option processing to something like...

```
option=argumentparse "$@"
[[ option == ""           ]] && helpShow
[[ option =~ -h|--help    ]] && helpShow
[[ option =~ -v|--version ]] && versionShow
[[ option =~ -G|--GUI     ]] && GUI=$TRUE
[[ option =~ --title      ]] && TITLE=${option["--title"]}
```

Here, an argumentparse() function resolves the various syntax possibilities into a consistent format, perhaps an associative array.

There must be something coded out there somewhere. Any ideas?

*(updated and retitled)*

Comment: Have you looked at [shflags](http://code.google.com/p/shflags/)?

Comment: Thanks for the info! Just checked it out. Some interesting things there but still pretty involved.

Comment: I've used a few different solutions, but eventually just settled for `getopts`.  I had to accept it's limitations, but it's a POSIX shell standard, so it felt like a worthwhile trade off.  I also avoid using shell loops, and agree they are generally inefficient, but I just bit the bullet for `getopts`.  I still might be able to point you in a solid direction.  What are your goals? Efficiency?  Portability?  Features?  Simplicity?  Which are your willing to compromise, to achieve the others?

Comment: 5min limit so had to add new comment... Thank you for jumping in! The most important goal would be simplicity/clarity of code using the solution. The function(s) could be fairly complex (use awk, sed, regex's, etc.) if they are "black boxes" that make the calling code easier to work with. Next would be "quality" of the function code which I define as a combination of consistency, symmetry and what we used to call "elegance". Third, would be efficiency, followed by features and portability to shells other than bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has been viewed so much (for me at least) but no answers were submitted, passing on the solution adopted...

**NOTE**
    Some functions, like the multi-interface output functions `ifHelpShow()` and `uiShow()` are used but not included here as their calls contain relevant information but their implementations do not.

```
###############################################################################
# FUNCTIONS (bash 4.1.0)
###############################################################################

function isOption () {
  # isOption "$@"
  # Return true (0) if argument has 1 or more leading hyphens.
  # Example:
  #     isOption "$@"  && ...
  # Note:
  #   Cannot use ifHelpShow() here since cannot distinguish 'isOption --help'
  #   from 'isOption "$@"' where first argument in "$@" is '--help'
  # Revised:
  #     20140117 docsalvage
  # 
  # support both short and long options
  [[ "${1:0:1}" == "-" ]]  && return 0
  return 1
}

function optionArg () {
  ifHelpShow "$1" 'optionArg  --option "$@"
    Echo argument to option if any. Within "$@", option and argument may be separated
    by space or "=". Quoted strings are preserved. If no argument, nothing echoed.
    Return true (0) if option is in argument list, whether an option-argument supplied
    or not. Return false (1) if option not in argument list. See also option().
    Examples:
        FILE=$(optionArg --file "$1")
        if $(optionArg -f "$@"); then ...
        optionArg --file "$@"   && ...
    Revised:
        20140117 docsalvage'  && return
  #
  # --option to find (without '=argument' if any)
  local FINDOPT="$1"; shift
  local OPTION=""
  local ARG=
  local o=
  local re="^$FINDOPT="
  #
  # echo "option start: FINDOPT=$FINDOPT, o=$o, OPTION=$OPTION, ARG=$ARG, @=$@" >&2
  #
  # let "$@" split commandline, respecting quoted strings
  for o in "$@"
  do
    # echo "FINDOPT=$FINDOPT, o=$o, OPTION=$OPTION, ARG=$ARG" >&2
    # echo " o=$o"  >&2
    # echo "re=$re" >&2
    #
    # detect --option and handle --option=argument
    [[ $o =~ $re ]]  && { OPTION=$FINDOPT; ARG="${o/$FINDOPT=/}"; break; }
    #
    # $OPTION will be non-null if --option was detected in last pass through loop
    [[ ! $OPTION ]]  && [[ "$o" != $FINDOPT ]]   && {              continue; } # is a positional arg (no previous --option)
    [[ ! $OPTION ]]  && [[ "$o" == $FINDOPT ]]   && { OPTION="$o"; continue; } # is the arg to last --option
    [[   $OPTION ]]  &&   isOption "$o"          && {                 break; } # no more arguments
    [[   $OPTION ]]  && ! isOption "$o"          && { ARG="$o";       break; } # only allow 1 argument
  done
  #
  # echo "option  final: FINDOPT=$FINDOPT, o=$o, OPTION=$OPTION, ARG=$ARG, @=$@" >&2
  #
  # use '-n' to remove any blank lines
  echo -n "$ARG"
  [[ "$OPTION" == "$FINDOPT" ]]   && return 0
  return 1
}

###############################################################################
# MAIN  (bash 4.1.0) (excerpt of relevant lines)
###############################################################################

# options
[[ "$@" == ""            ]]   && { zimdialog --help           ; exit 0; }
[[ "$1" == "--help"      ]]   && { zimdialog --help           ; exit 0; }
[[ "$1" == "--version"   ]]   && { uiShow "version $VERSION\n"; exit 0; }

# options with arguments
TITLE="$(optionArg --title  "$@")"
TIP="$(  optionArg --tip    "$@")"
FILE="$( optionArg --file   "$@")"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a great answer here but OP clearly asked for **simpler** processing of command line options. I think there can not be simpler way of parsing complex shell options than using `getopt` from *util-linux*:

```bsh
$ cat opts.sh 
#!/bin/bash

# Print usage and exit
usage() {
    exec >&2 # Write everything to STDERR (consistent with getopt errors)
    (($#)) && echo "$@"
    echo "Usage: $0 [opts...] [args...]"
    exit 1
}

# Use getopt to validate options and reorder them. On error print usage
OPTS=$(getopt -s bash -o 'ab:c' -l 'longopt,longopt2,longwitharg:' -- "$@") || usage

# Replace our arguments with the reordered version
eval set -- "$OPTS"

# At this point everything up to "--" is options
declare opt_a opt_c longopt longopt2 longwitharg
declare -a opt_b  # Array to accumulate -b arguments
while (($#))
do
    case $1 in
        -a) opt_a=1;;
        -b) opt_b+=("$2"); shift;;
        -c) ((++opt_c));;
        --longopt) longopt=1;;
        --longopt2) ((++longopt2));;
        --longwitharg) longwitharg=$2; shift;;
        --) shift; break;; # We're done with options, shift over "--" and move on...
        *) usage "Unknown argument: $1" # Should not happen unless getopt errors are ignored.
    esac
    # Always shift once (for options with arguments we already shifted in the case so it's the 2nd shift)
    shift
done

echo "Remaining arguments after parsing options: $#"
# Now you can work directly with "$@" or slurp it in an array
args=("$@")

# Here's what we're left with:
declare -p opt_a opt_b opt_c longopt longopt2 longwitharg

# This is how you iterate over an array which may contain spaces and other field separators
for file in "${args[@]}"
do
    echo "File arg: $file"
done
```

`getopt` will do its validation and return error (unless you tell it not to, then you can catch them yourself). For example:

```
$ ./opts.sh --badopt
getopt: unrecognized option '--badopt'
```

Everything else is ordered and quoted properly:

```
$ ./opts.sh -ab3 -b8 file1 -ccc --longopt --longwitharg=abc --longwitharg "abc def" "file with spaces" 
Remaining arguments after parsing options: 2
declare -- opt_a="1"
declare -a opt_b=([0]="3" [1]="8")
declare -- opt_c="3"
declare -- longopt="1"
declare -- longopt2
declare -- longwitharg="abc def"
File arg: file1
File arg: file with spaces
```

The arguments here:

- `-a` is a flag - set to 1 if present
- `-b` and be repeated, each instance is added to the `opt_b` array
- `-c` is a counter, counts the 3 occurrences
- `--longopt` is a flag like `-a`
- `--longopt2` is a counter like `-c` (not used in this example, so unset; it will still be treated as 0 in *Arithmetic Expansion*).
- `--longwitharg` is a normal option with argument. In this example we override its value later on the command line
- `file1` and `file with spaces` are the remaining arguments, and although they're specified at random places they both end up at the end after `--` once getopt reorders the command line.

Note that quoting variables is very important to properly handle arguments with spaces, although I've voluntarily avoided quotes where it's not needed such as:

- Direct variable assignment: `longwitharg=$2`
- Switch case: `case $1 in`

If unsure, extra quotes generally won't hurt.

Comment: Also note that if you have no short options you still have to pass an empty option string to getopt - i.e. `getopt -o '' [...]`.