# How to document my custom bash functions and aliases?

Tags: bash, alias, function, documentation

#### Problem:

I have multiple bash functions and aliases. I can't remember all of them off the top of my head, so I usually end up opening my `.bash_functions` and `.bash_aliases` files to find what I need.

#### Question(s):

How can I list functions/aliases available from the bash prompt?

Is it possible for me to document my bash functions/aliases using comments (kinda like PHPDoc)?

I'd just like a simple/nice way to output what's available without having to open the files. It would be cool to run a command and have it spit out a dynamic list of my functions/aliases (usage examples would be a plus). :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To list active aliases, run:

```
alias
```

To see names of all active functions, run:

```
declare -F
```

To see the names and definitions of all active functions, run:

```
declare -f
```

#### More

The information on aliases is also available is a script-friendly format with:

```
declare -p BASH_ALIASES
```

`man bash` provides more info on the `alias` builtin:

> ```
>    alias [-p] [name[=value] ...]
>           Alias with  no  arguments  or  with  the  -p
>           option  prints  the  list  of aliases in the
>           form alias name=value  on  standard  output.
>           When  arguments  are  supplied,  an alias is
>           defined for each name whose value is  given.
>           A  trailing  space in  value causes the next
>           word to be checked  for  alias  substitution
>           when  the  alias is expanded.  For each name
>           in the argument list for which no  value  is
>           supplied, the name and value of the alias is
>           printed.  Alias returns true unless  a  name
>           is   given  for  which  no  alias  has  been
>           defined.
> ```

Regarding functions, `man bash` explains that `declare` can provide still more information is available if the `extdebug` option is set:

> ```
>    Function  names  and definitions may be listed with
>    the -f option to the  declare  or  typeset  builtin
>    commands.  The -F option to declare or typeset will
>    list the function names only  (and  optionally  the
>    source  file and line number, if the extdebug shell
>    option is enabled).
> ```

#### Links

1. http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html
2. http://linfo.org/alias.html

Comment: Ha! Too easy. Thanks! That's pretty easy. Any tips on listing custom functions?

Comment: @mhulse Your welcome.  See update for functions.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I see you added the `declare` info. Thank you! I could live with `declare` and `alias` for quick and easy viewing. I just noticed that I can do `declare -f tree` which spits out only the `tree` function. Cool! I'm sold. Thanks again! (I can accept this as answer in 4 minutes.)

Comment: @ashumeow The ss64.com's text at http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html with their copyright and distribution terms http://ss64.com/docs/copyright.html (non-commercial!) **BREAK the terms of GFDL**--the license of the bash manual, because they include text from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html: commercial use of the derivative works of the Bash manual should be allowed. Their compilation without references doesn't seem nice for this and similar attribution reasons.

Comment: You may find the technique illustrated in [Simpler processing of shell script options](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65160/simpler-processing-of-shell-script-options) to be of use.

Answer (score 8):

I use the following function and javadoc like comments to create a --help option for my scripts:

```
PROG=$0 #The program name, used within doHelp

# Print a help message
# doHelp uses lines starting with ## to create the output
# the tags {@param ...} and {@code ...} colorize words
doHelp() {
grep '^##' "${PROG}" |
sed -e 's/^##[[:space:]]*//' |
while read line; do
    if ( echo "${line}" | grep -q '{@param [^}]*}' ); then
        # color parameter and echo evaulated value
        eval echo -e $(echo ${line} | sed \
            -e 's/^\(.*\){@param \([^}]*\)}\(.*\)$/\
            \"\1\\\\E[32;40m\2\\\\E[37;40m\\t(value: \"$\2\")\3\"/');
    else
        # other color commands
        echo -e $(echo ${line} | sed \
            -e 's/{@code \([^}]*\)}/\\E[36;40m\1\\E[37;40m/g');
    fi
done;
}
```

At https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/blob/master/Search/zylabPatisClient/src/main/scripts/generateReport.sh you can see how it's used within an actual script.

Comment: This is really cool! I wish I could give out green check marks for multiple answers. Thanks Kasper! I can't wait to try this out. :)

Comment: I keep getting `grep: : No such file or directory` when trying to run it via unix/bash as a function. … I know this question is old, but could you give an example as to how one would run this just as only a bash function via command line? Thanks!!! :)

Comment: @mhulse, I forgot to mention that you need to define `PROG=$0`; answer updated.

Comment: Thanks Kasper! I really want to get this to work, but I'm not having any luck so far. I'd hate to keep bugging you, but could you provide an example call from bash command line? Also, how could I set up `--help` or `-help` (i.e., `if echo "$@" | egrep -q -e '(-h)|(--help)'; then ...`. I'd love to setup my `.bash_functions`/`aliases` to allow for `aliasname -h` or `function arg --help`. Thanks again!

Comment: @mhulse The example call from the commandline `generateReport.sh` itself is only useful if you like to index medical documents via Zylab and query them via Aida. However, to try the help function use the following: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/master/Search/zylabPatisClient/src/main/scripts/generateReport.sh && chmod a+x generateReport.sh && ./generateReport.sh --help`.  How to achieve the second part with using `aliasname` in .bash_functions I do not (yet) know.

Comment: Thanks Kasper! I understand now. I really appreciate the clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been self-documenting bash functions in my `~./bashrc` with the `:` (null) built-in. The benefit is that it won't execute anything when run, but will show when printed.

```
$ declare -f my_function
my_function() {
    : My function does this and that
    echo "foo"
}
$ my_function
foo
```